# Keep dragbox visible

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm using a dragbox to capture coordinates from an openlayers 3 map.  Is there a way to keep the dragbox visible once you release the mouse buttom and have it disappear only once you start a new dragbox?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation in v3.7.0:

You have two events listeners on the dragbox, `boxend` and `boxstart`. Use `boxend` to create a new polygon ([look at this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/drag-features.html?q=polygon)), pass it the dragbox coordinates and then add it to the map. If you want to remove the dragbox once you start drawing a new one, remove the current active polygon from the map on `boxstart`.

Here is the code:

```
// Make the layer variable global to the two functions so we can access it in both functions
let layer;
dragBox.on('boxend', (evt) => {
  // Get the current dragbox coordinateds 
  let coordinates = dragBox.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  // Create the polygon and pass the coordinates
  let polygonFeature = new ol.Feature(
                       new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinates));

  // Create the layer and style it as you like
  layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [polygonFeature]
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 1,
        color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [127, 166, 59, 0.3]
      })
    })
  });

  // Assuming that you have a map instance, add the created layer to the map
  map.addLayer(layer);
});

// To remove the layer when you start drawing a new dragbox
dragBox.on('boxstart', (evt) => {
  map.removeLayer(layer);
});
```